# SONAR COBOL rule: "Procedures should share a naming convention in a PERFORM procedure THRU 'prefix'procedure"

Tags: sonarqube, cobol

want to code -EXIT suffix rather than END- prefix, but can't delete prefix. any thoughts appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Not a clue. You'd best demonstrate what you mean. `END-` could be the start of a scope-terminator. `-EXIT' is a conventional way of indicating a paragraph which exists so that someone can later add a `GO TO`, but only if that's the easiest thing for them to do (it always is). The -EXIT paragraph will, by the `THRU`, mark the scope of a `PERFORM`. Now, what do you mean?

Comment: "but can't delete prefix"?  if you are the coder, you can name your paragraphs and procedures whatever you want.  But it sounds like whatever you want to do is at odds with the SonarQube standards that your team has adopted.

Comment: thanks. we're trying to update the standard. sorry that wasn't clear. when we clear END- in the prefix field of the admin panel it turns gray, but doesn't disappear. later when we check the rule we see we have both the -EXIT suffix we want and the END- prefix we don't. wondering if we need to enter "" or a keyword like NONE to tell SONAR we really don't want the prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/COBOL-1320) which should be fixed in the next version.

Comment: Pierre - we attempted to back out our -EXIT suffix change until we have the fix, but can't. the default for suffix is already an empty string. when will the new release be available? thanks.

Comment: hit enter to soon. let me re-state: we attempted to back out our -EXIT suffix change until we have the fix, but can't. i.e. we can't specify an empty string once it's been changed to a non-empty string even if the default is an empty string. thought it important to make you aware of this refinement to the problem description. thanks.

Comment: I updated the [issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/COBOL-1320). As a general note, you can contact SonarSource support to get help on such problems.

Answer (score 1):

This [Sonarqube Rule](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=cobol%3ACOBOL.PerformThruProcedureNamingConventionCheck) has a default convention of 'END-' as prefix. But as it is documented, it can be changed by setting the parameter suffix as '-EXIT'.

Comment: Funny default. I see '-EXIT' all the time, and can't remember seeing 'END-' at all.

Comment: thanks. that's what we're trying to do, change from END- prefix to -EXIT suffix, but we end up with both. how can we tell sonar we want the suffix, but not the prefix? that is the question. we did the intuititve thing, by clearing the prefix and entering the suffix, but it didn't work.

Comment: If things are not worked as promised, it should be the bug in the version that you are using. You may report the issue. Btw, how do you specify the parameters for the rule?

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove the troublesome and error causing exit paragraphs and related perform/thru constructs and just go to a straight perform everywhere?  You can get the same effect and remove a source of hard to detect, annoying bugs.